# Step back by line in file

Tags: perl, file, loops, iteration

I'm iterating through a file and after some condition I have to step back by a line

when file line match the regexp, the second while loop goes in and it iterates over a file until it match `while`'s condition, after than my code have to STEP BACK by 1 line!

```
while(my $line = <FL>){
 if($line =~ /some regexp/){
   while($line =~ /^\+/){
      $line = <FL>; #Step into next line
   }
   seek(FL, -length($line), 1); #This should get me back the previous line
   #Some tasks with previous line
 }
}
```

actually `seek` should work but it doesn't, it return me the same line... What is the problem?

Comment: The position argument to [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) needs to be in *bytes*

Comment: what is the second `$line = <FL>;` for? and then you immediately use seek to get the original value of `$line` immediately?

Comment: @Hamster the second `$line = <FL>` is for stepping into the next line of the file... this need to be done in my case

Comment: @Rocker but then it seems like you immediately go back a line?

Comment: well when going into second `while` loop, the fileline contains `+` in it so im iterating over these lines with `while($line =~ /^\+/)` but I need to get the last line with `+` so i have to step back by a line after going out from the `while` loop... a little complex problem :D

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Explain what exactly you're trying to do, not *how* you're trying to do it. You'll probably get better answers that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read from a filehandle, it has already advanced to the next line.  Therefore if you go back the length of the current line, all you're doing is setting up to read the line over again.

Also, relating the `length` of a line to its length on disk assumes the encoding is `:raw` instead of `:crlf` or some other format.  This is a big assumption.

What you need are state variables to keep track of your past values.  There is no need to literally roll back a file handle.

The following is a stub of what you might be aiming to do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @buffer;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (my $range = /some regexp/ ... !/^\+/) {
        if ($range =~ /E/) {                   # Last Line of range
            print @buffer;
        }
    }

    # Save a buffer of last 4 lines
    push @buffer, $_;
    shift @buffer if @buffer > 4;
}

__DATA__
stuff
more stuff
some regexp
+ a line
+ another line
+ last line
break out
more stuff
ending stuff
```

Output:

```
some regexp
+ a line
+ another line
+ last line
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like: (as an alternative)

```
open(my $fh, '<', "$file") or die $!;#use three argument open
my $previous_line = q{}; #initially previous line would be empty
while(my $current_line = <$fh>){
  chomp;
  print"$current_line\n";
  print"$previous_line\n";
  #assign current line into previous line before it go to next line
  $previous_line = $current_line; 
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: i was thinking about this but it's not a solution for me.

Comment: Then you are not asking your question properly